# Was Sudarshan Chakra given by Lord Shiva to Lord Vishnu?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, vishnu, ramayana, sudarsana

Many puranas says that Lord Shiva had given Sudarshan Chakra to Lord Vishnu. But what epics like Valmiki Ramayana & Mahabharata says about it? Does anybody had created it? Who was the creator of this Sudarshan Chakra - Shiva or Vishwakarma?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Sudarshana Chakra has many legends associated with it. I don't think it is mentioned as such in Ramayana and Mahabharata.

However it is mentioned in chapter 34 of KotiRudra Samhita in Shiva Purana that Lord Shiva gave Sudarshan Chakra to Lord Vishnu.

This chapter, named as [Acquisition of Sudarshana by Vishnu](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226535.html) reads as follows-

> Vyāsa said:—
>
> 1. O great sages, on hearing the words of Sūta the sages praised him and spoke desiring the welfare of the worlds.
>
> The sages said:—
>
> 2. O Sūta, you know everything. Hence we ask you. O holy lord, please narrate the greatness of the phallic image Harīśvara.
> 3. O dear, this was heard by us formerly that by propitiating Harīśvara, Viṣṇuacquired his discus Sudarśana. Please narrate that
>    story particularly.
>
> Sūta said:—
>
> 4. O great sages, may the auspicious story of Harīśvara be heard, how Sudarśana was acquired by Viṣṇu formerly from Śiva.
> 5. On a certain occasion the Daityas became very powerful. They harassed the worlds and violated sacred rites.
> 6. Tormented by the Daityas of great strength and exploit, the gods narrated their misery to Viṣṇu, their saviour.
>
> The gods said:—
>
> 7. O lord, be merciful. We are very much afflicted by the Daityas. Where shall we go? What shall we do? We have resorted to you, for you
>    are worthy of seeking refuge by us.
>
> Sūta said:—
>
> 8. On hearing these words of the gods distressed in mind, Viṣṇu remembered the lotus-like feet of Śiva and said.
>
> Viṣṇu said:—
>
> 9. O gods, I shall carry out your task after propitiating Śiva. These powerful enemies shall be conquered with great effort.
>
> Sūta said:—
>
> 10. Thus consoled by lord Viṣṇu, the gods thought that the Daityas would be surely killed. They then went to their respective abodes.
> 11. For the victory of the gods, Viṣṇu worshipped śiva, the lord of all the gods, the imperishable and the cosmic witness of all.
> 12. He went to Kailāsa and dug a pit there wherein he kindled fire and performed penance.
> 13. He worshipped Śiva joyously with various mantras and hymns prescribed for the worship of earthen image.
> 14. O great sages, he worshipped with the lotus-flowers growing in the Mānasa lake. He sat firmly in the Yogic posture and did not move
>     at all.
> 15. Thinking decisively—“By all means I shall stay here till the lord is pleased” Viṣṇu worshipped Śiva.
> 16. O brahmins, when Śiva was not pleased with Viṣṇu, the latter began to think anxiously.
> 17. After thinking thus he rendered him various services. Still, lord Śiva, indulging in divine sports was not satisfied.
> 18. Surprised much at this, Viṣṇu, endowed with great devotion, eulogised lord Śiva by reciting his thousand names with pleasure.
> 19. Repeating every name, he worshipped Śiva, favourably disposed towards those who seek refuge in him? with a lotus flower.
> 20. In order to test the piety of Viṣṇu, one of the thousand lotus-flowers was taken away by Śiva.
> 21. That wonderful Māyā of Śiva was not noticed by Viṣṇu. But when he came to know of the shortage he started to search.
> 22. In order to find it out he roamed over the world, steadily maintaining his sacred rite. But not finding the same, the pious Viṣṇu
>     offered one of his eyes (instead of the lotus).
> 23. On seeing it Śiva who destroys all miseries was delighted and appeared before him. He spoke these words to Viṣṇu.
>
> Śiva said:—
>
> 24. O Viṣṇu, I am delighted with you. Mention the boon you wish to have. I shall grant you what you desire. There is nothing which cannot
>     be given to you.
>
> Sūta said:—
>
> 25. On hearing the words of Śiva, Viṣṇu was pleased in his mind. Extremely delighted he spoke to Śiva with palms joined in reverence.
>
> Viṣṇu said:—
>
> 26. What is there to be mentioned to you? You are the immanent soul. Still, O Lord, I mention the same with due deference to your behest.
> 27. O Sadāśiva, the entire universe is afflicted by the Daityas. We have no pleasure at all. Our weapons are in effectual in killing the
>     Daityas.
> 28. What shall I do? Where shall I go? I have no greater saviour than you. O lord, I seek refuge in you.
>
> Sūta said:—
>
> 29. After saying this he stood in affliction and bowed to Śiva, the supreme soul.
> 30. On hearing these words of Viṣṇu, Śiva, the lord of gods, gave him his discus Sudarśana shining with the mass of splendour.
> 31. On receiving it Viṣṇu slew the powerful demons immediately with the discus without any strain.
> 32. Thereupon the universe derived normalcy, the gods became happy. After receiving the Sudarśana missile Viṣṇu was greatly delighted.
>
> The sages said:—
>
> 33. What is that hymn of Śiva that consists of his thousand names? What is that hymn whereby Śíva was so much delighted that he gave
>     Viṣṇu the discus.
> 34. Please expound the glory of this hymn to us and narrate the dialogue between Śiva and Viṣṇu. The merciful nature of Śiva towards
>     Viṣṇu may also be narrated to us.
>
> Vyāsa said:—
>
> 35. On hearing the words of the pious sages, Sūta spoke after remembering the lotus-like feet of Śiva.

Shiva Purana is Shaiva Purana as evident by its name. Vaishnavas puranas might have different legend associated with Sudarsana.

Comment: giving complete chapter makes it lengthy..30. is the most relevant here, u can add 30. +1/2 shloka before and after it instead of compete chapter.

Comment: @YDS well I left as it is for giving the background as well as the story of Lord Vishnu giving His eye instead of lotus to Lord Shiva as a test of devotion as present in Shiva Purana.